# Ошибки: does not name a type

Tags: windows, qt, winapi, usb

Я использую [этот пример](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2935184/how-to-get-vendor-id-and-product-id-of-a-plugged-usb-device-on-windows) для отображения информации о, подключённом через USB, устройстве. Я пишу на С++, использую Qt под Windows. Мне надо получить: название модели, изготовителя и серийный номер устройства.

Но у меня компилятор выдаёт в консоле ошибки. Причём не в файле, где код, а в подключаемых библиотеках. Ошибки: `does not name a type`

```
ошибка: 'LONG' does not name a type typedef LONG HRESULT; 
ошибка: typedef 'UINT' is initialized (use decltype instead) typedef UINT (CALLBACK *LPFNPSPCALLBACKA)(HWND hwnd,UINT uMsg,struct _PROPSHEETPAGEA *ppsp); 
ошибка: 'CALLBACK' was not declared in this scope
ошибка: 'DWORD' does not name a type PROPSHEETPAGEA_V1_FIELDS
...
```

[Тут](https://oroboro.com/usb-serial-number/) тоже описано как получить серийный номер. Но та же проблема, ошибки: `does not name a type`.

Я подключаю библиотеку `#include <Setupapi.h>`. Что я упускаю. Почему не работает?

Comment: 1) Картинки битые, 0 размер. 2) Больше кода, 3) ошибки свидетельствуют, что вы забыли подключить <windows.h> (BaseTsd.h; WinDef.h; WinNT.h)

Comment: @goldstar_labs Теперь только 8 ошибок, а не 800.  ошибка: undefined reference to `_imp__SetupDiGetClassDevsW@16'  в строке HANDLE hInfo = SetupDiGetClassDevs(&GUID_DEVINTERFACE_USB_DEVICE,NULL,NULL, DIGCF_PRESENT | DIGCF_INTERFACEDEVICE);

Comment: вместе с libusb должен быть .lib файл, его необходимо подключить к проекту с помощью настроек проекта или директивы #pragma comment(lib, "path_to_lib_file")

Comment: @goldstar_labs в каком файле это прописывать? .pro или .cpp

Comment: #pragma comment(lib, "path_to_lib_file") - в срр, в конфигах qt не силен)

Comment: @goldstar_labs помогло в .pro LIBS += -lhid -lsetupapi . Спасибо за помощь

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/78142/discussion-between-ivan-triumphov-and-goldstar-labs).

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/78149/discussion-between-ivan-triumphov-and-goldstar-labs).